# Checking how much memory MATLAB asks for

Tags: matlab, memory

I was wondering if there is a way of knowing how much memory a function or a session in MATLAB that runs out of memory **asked for**.

For example, when MATLAB sends an `Out of memory` error, does the OS (Windows and/or Linux) register the event of MATLAB requesting more memory than the OS could give it?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to call:

```
dbstop if error
```

When the error is thrown, MATLAB will go in debug mode and jump to the offending line, that way you can find how much memory was requested...

Comment: Thanks @Amro, would you mind elaborating your answer a bit more?

Comment: basically this is a way to tell MATLAB to enter debugging mode whenever an error occurs (such as "out of memory"). Once that happens, it will open the editor pointing to the line that caused the error. You can then interact the same way you do while debugging; For example if the line was `x=rand(N);` you can find out the value of `N` say using the command prompt or by just hovering over the variable `N` - for this example lets assume something big like `N=10000`, thus trying to allocate 10000*10000*8 bytes. MEMORY function should tell how much memory is available

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amro. I didn't know about `dbstop in error`, that's a great trick! I use `keyboard` often to enter debug mode and grow my code organically in it. I guess I'm still curious to know if there is a more direct way of checking how much memory MATLAB asks when it runs out of memory..

Comment: `dbstop if error` is equivalent to the menu item Debug -> Stop if Errors/Warnings, which shows all the assorted `dbstop`/`dbclear` commands relating to things that go wrong. It's probably my most frequently used menu item.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to get a direct answer from MATLAB on how much memory it is trying to allocate. I just tried profiling a `rand(10000)` using `profile -memory on`, and there are no memory statistics for the line with the failed allocation. (Thanks to Undocumented MATLAB for this profiler hint. [link](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-profiler-options/))